# Form field not showing with the default UI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I m trying to create an angular material form following the example from this link

https://stackblitz.com/angular/deykmvkxjok?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

However the result is that the form is displaying white[image]

**component.html**

```
   <div class="card p-6">
      <h2 class="m-0 title mb-6">
        Title
      </h2>
      <h1 class="display-1 m-0">Title</h1>
      <h3 class="title mt-0 text-secondary">Test</h3>
      
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
        <input matInput>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
//    this.form = this.fb.group({
//    });
  }

}
```

**The scss is empty**

Comment: any console error?

Comment: the stackblitz works fine for me. is there a possibility you are using a very old browser?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the module of the component (component.module.ts) where I had missed the

```
MatInputModule
```

import

Comment: Maybe as the docs say you should also add ```<div class="form-container">``` in the top of your form.